# Ignore AndroidX and Want to use android support libraries alone in Android Studio 3.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-support-library, androidx

In my project I used Android support libraries previously. After upgrading to the Android Studio 3.2 AS loads AndroidX and some other support libraries(e.g. com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) by default. This gives me lot of manifest merger failed error. I tried enabling jetifier but actually I don't want to use AndroidX. I just wanted to use support libraries 28.0.0 only. So my question is how can I ignore that AndroidX packages which is loaded by default. So that I can use support libraries.

Comment: Please add your `build.gradle` files. What do you mean by "loads AndroidX packages"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "REFACTOR" and then
2. Click on "Migrate to AndroidX"
3. It will ask to make a backup of your current project , so check the CheckBox then click 
   on Migrate.
4. It will create a ".Zip" file of your project.
5. It will ask again to change all the implementations to AndroidX , click Okay and.
6. All your implementations will be migrated to AndroidX.
7. At last you need to change your <....> angular bracket lines related to Androidx.
8. If you are migrating your exixting project you need to change this mandatory or if you 
   are creating a new project than it will do it by its own.
9. Example "android.support.v7.widget.CardView" to "androidx.cardview.widget.CardView"